# How to use Twitter Bootstrap's glyphicons with Rails's button_to

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a couple buttons that submit AJAX requests.

```
<%= button_to 'GO!', {controller:'videos', action:'rate', id: video.hashed_id, format: 'json'}, {:remote=>true, :class=>"btn btn-default btn-sm"} %>
```

If I replace `GO!` with `<span class="glyphicaon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>` it ends up causing this `value="<span class="glyphicaon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>"`

Any ideas how I can get a glyphicon into a button that submits a form?

**Update**

I tried this:

```
<%= button_to content_tag(:i, '', class: 'icon-thumbs-up'), {controller:'videos', action:'rate', id: video.hashed_id, format: 'json'}, {:remote=>true, :class=>"btn btn-default btn-sm"} %>
```

which created this:

```
<form action="/videos/rate/asdfsxsdf/no.json" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post">
<div><input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="es4wPqFr9xPBUFsbHQR/gAzofDC+ZwYsiiJ7RAQZUHk=" />
</div></form>
```

Comment: To use glyphicons you need to use a <button> tag. Ruby `button_to` helper renders `<input type="submit"/>`. It's not possible without overriding what `button_to` does. If you don't need the form and a submit you can use the `button_tag` helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't super sexy, but it works!!

```
<%= form_tag({controller:'videos', action:'rate', id: video.hashed_id, yesno:'no', format: 'json'}, {remote:true} ) do %>
<%= button_tag '', :class=>"rate-btn yes-btn btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" %>
<% end %>
```

Basically (as mentioned in the comments above), the issue is that the syntax used by glyphicon can't be used on self-closing elements like `<input />` so you need a button. Unfortunately Rails's `button_to` also generates an `<input />` (inside of a form). You could write the form by hand with a  but you'll run into problems with Rails's built-in forgery prevention system (you need an authenticity token). So instead, I combine the `form_tag` and the `button_tag` with corresponding classes and we're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

With Rails 3/4 and bootstrap this works:

```
              <%= button_to "/hubspot/new_campaign?id=tab1-2", :class=>"btn btn-default btn-icon glyphicons
              message_plus", :remote => true do %>
                  <i></i>Create New Campaign
              <% end %>
```

Comment: this works in rails 4 for me. I think this is the best solution here. Thanks @Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<%= button_to content_tag(:i, '', class: 'icon-thumbs-up'), {controller:'videos', action:'rate', id: video.hashed_id, format: 'json'}, {:remote=>true, :class=>"btn btn-default btn-sm"} %>`

Comment: Your code is throwing errors as-is, and I can't find it documentation for that function anywhere. Can you either confirm that it works, or direct me to docs for it.

Comment: I got it to work without errors but it still results in the markup being injected into `value=''` attribute. I added the results above.

Answer (score 0):

I think **.html_safe** can solve your problem. I would try replacing 'GO!' with:

```
'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>'.html_safe
```

OR if you still wanted text

```
'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> GO!'.html_safe
```

### Using Bootstrap 3

According to the Bootstrap 3 documentation for [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons), a large button with a Star glyphicon on the left and the text Star to the right o can be achieved using the following HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

With button_tag in Rails, this is how you would create that same button:

```
<%= button_tag '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star'.html_safe , :class=>"btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
```

Similarly, if you wanted the icon after the text, it would be like this:

```
<%= button_tag 'Star <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>'.html_safe , :class=>"btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
```

**NB:** Don't forget the space between the closing span tag and the text of the button.

### Using Bootstrap 2

According to the Bootstrap 2 documentation for [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons), a large Star button with the text Star to the right can be achieved using the following HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-large" href="#"><i class="icon-star"></i> Star</a>
```

With button_tag in Rails, you can create the same button using:

```
<%= button_tag '<i class="icon-star"></i> Star'.html_safe , :class=>"btn btn-large" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something a little more comprehensive ... a button with verbiage and the glyph on it. I mixed and matched from the above answers, but this is a little different. Wrapping the pieces in a span tag did the trick:

In HAML

```
 = button_to(rails_path(:id => id), :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-
     success) do
   %span
     %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-star
     Star!
```

After some interpolation, that generates (in rails 5)

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/rails/path?id=1734369" data-remote="true">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
      <span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              Star!                
      </span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="blah" />
</form>
```