# Is it possible to use Glychicons in form submit buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have no problem making buttons with glyphicons in them, but I always create an `<a class="btn..."`. This *doesn't* work: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="" />`. It just produces a blank button.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Of course it does, you're setting the value to `""`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Tried <button class='btn btn-success'><i class='icon-plus'></i>Save</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CAN be done while still using the Form Helper methods. Check out the solution here: [How to use Twitter Bootstrap's glyphicons with Rails's button_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546902/how-to-use-twitter-bootstraps-glyphicons-with-railss-button-to)

Answer (score 1):

I do had problems in the past with use of `<input>` markup. Maybe you could try with the `<button>` one.

Here is what done in the bootsrap doc :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
</button>
```

See [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) about glyphicons if you need.

Hope it helps you :p

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons use "after" or "before" psuedo element, which is not supported for non-container tags, or those that self close, like inputs. So if you wish to use the input submit (and yes I understand you, I've been there before) recreate it like this:

```
<span class="glyph class here"><input type="submit" value="whatever" /></span>
```

Edit, some tweaking is needed for the span, you need to make it look like a button, and then a bit more tweaking for the submit button inside:

```
input[type="submit"] {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```